# CoffeeScript dynamic methods

Tags: metaprogramming, coffeescript

I'm trying to create methods dynamically in coffee script, but as my code shows, the iterator I use to create the methods doesn't reset its variables between iterations and so I en up with shared variables that conflicts:

```
class MyClass
  constructor: (@name) ->

  for k, v of ['get', 'set']
    console.log('creating method: ' + v)
    MyClass::[v] = (args...) ->
      method = v
      console.log('executing method: ' + method)

o = new MyClass('dummy')
o.get()
o.set()
```

Outputs:

```
> creating method: get
> creating method: set
> executing method: set
> executing method: set
```

one knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, you can change your mind and accept Trevor's answer instead. Using `do` is probably more idiomatic than a separate function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inner function:

```
(args...) ->
  method = v
  console.log('executing method: ' + method)
```

is actually a closure on `v` so when it is executed, `v` will evaluate to its last value in the loop (i.e. `set`). Looks like you just need a bit of closure busting:

```
build_method = (v) ->
  (args...) ->
    method = v
    console.log('executing method: ' + method)
```

And then:

```
for k, v of ['get', 'set']
  console.log('creating method: ' + v)
  MyClass::[v] = build_method(v)
```

Keep in mind that CoffeeScript is just JavaScript with different makeup so it suffers from a lot of the same problems (as does any language with closures) and those problems have the same solutions.

Comment: thanks, It worked with your logic.  I only added the method creation inside the constructor method to have access to class vars and methods.

Comment: @loophole: That was pretty much a transliteration of the same thing you'd do in JavaScript. You just need to force `v` to be evaluated at the right time using a separate function call.

Answer (score 7):

mu has correctly diagnosed the problem. The most direct solution is to use the CoffeeScript language's `do` keyword, which creates and runs an inner function that captures the values of the variables you pass in:

```
for k, v of ['get', 'set']
  do (k, v) ->
    console.log('creating method: ' + v)
    MyClass::[v] = (args...) ->
      method = v
      console.log('executing method: ' + method)
```

I talk about this feature in my PragPub article, [A CoffeeScript Intervention](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2011-05/a-coffeescript-intervention).

Comment: Does `do` exist specifically for closure busting? I can see other uses for it but it smells like it was added specifically for this particular use case.

Comment: It was indeed. Pre-1.0, `for` loops automatically captured variables for you, but this created other problems (e.g. `break`/`continue` wouldn't work), so `do` (previously proposed) was added in just before the 1.0 release. See [issue 959](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/959).

Comment: It's also handy for creating a self executing closure anywhere.  `do -> somePrivateVar = 'foo'`